# The WebPart menu doesn't work in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I created a WebPart,and it works in SharePoint 2007,I can edit or delete it.But the menu of this WebPart does't work in SharePoint 2010,when I click the menu,it shows nothing.I can't delete or edit it.
The error message is "The value of the property 'UpdateWebPartMenuFocus' is null or undefined, not a Function object",which points to:

```
UpdateWebPartMenuFocus(this, 'ms-wpselectlinkfocus', 'ms-WPEditTextVisible')
```

So I want to know the probable reasons for this problem,or any mistake I may have made with my codes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `UpdateWebPartMenuainFocus` is defined in Core.js.

You need a reference to Core.js, either from your page or from a master page that your page uses.